# Tax Query not generating correct query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, tax-query

I have the following query setup to pull videos from a custom post type by category:

```
$cat_name = single_cat_title('', FALSE);

$videos = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $cat_name
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

When I echo the $cat_name variable, I'm getting the correct category name. However, when I output the request for the query, what I'm getting is:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( 0 = 1 ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'video' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

With no reference to the tax_query.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong that is not triggering the tax query portion of the query?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have 2 arrays in `tax_query` part ? The 2 strange parts are "1=1" and "0=1". Looking at youre query, they must map to "tax_query" and "posts_per_page". Be sure you use the right syntaxe for those 2 items...

Comment: The tax_query parameter is an array of arrays: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters, this is why I wrote my code that way.

The second query is what WordPress is outputting... it's not something I'm writing explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you didn't write the 2nd one, but you see there which parameters are well interpreted, and which are not. The 2 only missing parameters are "tax_query" and "posts_per_page", so the strange generated part must come from those 2 fields. What if you remove "posts_per_pages" ?

Comment: Working on that @Random...

Comment: Never use term names in a `tax_query`, there is a known issue which I have explained in the post I marked as duplicate. You should use another method to either get the term slug or the term ID and then pass that to the `tax_query`

Comment: That is not the case here @pietergoosen. There are no special characters in this category name, but I will look at that question and see if can't help me out. Thanks.

Comment: cat_name contains "People".

Comment: That post does not only apply to special characters, but to any term name where the name consists of two words or more ;-)

Comment: Thank you guys. You set me on the right path to fix this. Should I just update my question with the correct code or create an answer?

Comment: Last question (related I hope, but will open a new question if it's better) - I removed 'posts_per_page' for my solution to work. When I add it back it, it breaks the query completely. How can I tell the query to return an unlimited amount of posts if 'posts_per_page' isn't working with the query?

Comment: *it breaks the query completely* Meaning what. Try `'nopaging' => true`, if that does not work, please start a new question. Just before you do, try `'suppress_filters' => true` in your query args as well to make sure that it is not a bad filter, and add `remove_all_filters( 'pre_get_posts' );` before the query to make sure it is not a bad `pre_get_posts` action causing the issue